# Succulent identification

Tags: identification, succulents

I had a small succulent plant that sat indoors (in Austin, TX) and did absolutely nothing for years.  Then in the spring of 2010 it produced this:

[image]

A long tendril with delicate flowers.  The dimensions of what is visible in the image are about 2 inches across, 4 inches tall.  Here's a picture of the whole plant

[image]

I'd like to identify it if possible so I can obtain another one.

If I do find another one, is there a method to induce this flowering, or does one just have to wait years?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's an [Echeveria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echeveria) of some sort.  Just pick off one of the daughter plants from the side and pot it up, for your new plant. No further purchase required. Mine live in an Unheated greenhouse in the uk over winter and on the step of the house for the summer, frost free. Kept dry in well drained soil. They flower each year.

Comment: Yes your spelling is correct, mine isn't apologies.. They are usually relatively cheap to purchase if you can find them.

Answer (score 2):

This Echeveria looks very similar to a variety called 'topsy turvy' (Echeveria Runyonii) which is available for sale[image] in Austin, TX. It flowers in a very showy orange, the color of the plant itself is an icy silver-blue and it is also more cold hardy than is typical for an echeveria going all the way down to 20degrees, and making it (if you have a mild winter) a year round outdoor plant. It has a freakish growth form which can only be propigated vegitatively and is one of the only Echeveria that will stay true to its altered form when grown from cuttings. It tends to send out a lot of new baby plants and can form colonies fairly quickly. It tends to bloom in late summer/early fall.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I live in Portland, OR now and it might not do so well up here at 45°N :-)